# Calculating totals in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to use JavaScript in Acrobat to total up 10 data fields in an interactive form. Originally, the data was to be entered manually. The calculation formula we created works when the data is entered manually, but doesn't total properly when the data is exported from another form and then imported into this form using an FDF file.

The current workflow uses three forms. Data is entered into forms 1 & 2. Then the data is exported from both forms as data and saved in FDF format.

Form 3 is opened and the the two data files are imported into this form. There are two TOTALS fields with similar formulas, one adds up all the negative numbers, the other adds up all the positive numbers.

But, when we import both files only the first calculation fires. The second is ignored. If you import either of the data files a second time the second calculation fires off.

So, we're trying to figure out how to tell Acrobat to do BOTH calculations once the data files are imported.

Here is the JavaScript code for the negative numbers:

```
function calcLost(){
 var amountLost = 0;
 var pt_neck_diff = this.getField('pt_neck_diff').value;
 var pt_arm_r_diff = this.getField('pt_arm_r_diff').value;
 var pt_arm_l_diff = this.getField('pt_arm_l_diff').value;
 var pt_chest_diff = this.getField('pt_chest_diff').value;
 var pt_belly_diff = this.getField('pt_belly_diff').value;
 var pt_waist_diff = this.getField('pt_waist_diff').value;
 var pt_hips_diff = this.getField('pt_hips_diff').value;
 var pt_butt_diff = this.getField('pt_butt_diff').value;
 var pt_thigh_r_diff = this.getField('pt_thigh_r_diff').value;
 var pt_thigh_l_diff = this.getField('pt_thigh_l_diff').value;
 if(pt_neck_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_neck_diff
 }

 if(pt_arm_r_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_arm_r_diff
 }

 if(pt_arm_l_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_arm_l_diff
 }

 if(pt_chest_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_chest_diff
 }

 if(pt_belly_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_belly_diff
 }

 if(pt_waist_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_waist_diff
 }

 if(pt_hips_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_hips_diff
 }

 if(pt_butt_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_butt_diff
 }

 if(pt_thigh_r_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_thigh_r_diff
 }

 if(pt_thigh_l_diff < 0){
   amountLost += pt_thigh_l_diff
 }
 return amountLost;
 }

 event.value = calcLost();
```

The other (nearly identical) script calculates the Positive numbers. Anyone have a clue how to tell Acrobat to run the second script?

As mentioned earlier, both formulas work fine if you re-import either one of the data files. It just doesn't work properly when the files are first imported.

Another interesting fact is that in a similar form a derivative calculation that uses only only four figures works fine. When we use the form with 10 data fields the formula doesn't work.

We are stumped.

Comment: which event are you using to trigger the calculation?

Comment: The calculations are in the form fields. They calculate when the data is imported.

Comment: Form fields have several events where javascript code can be placed (validate, format and calculate for example). As far as I know, if you put your code in the calculate event, it will only change when a user (a person) modifies a value of a form field. Programmatic modifications will not (in general) trigger the event.

Comment: Is there a way to get the calculation to trigger on import?

Comment: Not that I am aware off... but I could be wrong.

Comment: Can we add a button to the form that would force the calculations to trigger after import? If so, what would the trigger be?

Comment: You could indeed try adding a hidden dummy field and a button, then change the hidden field value to some random text when the button is clicked. This should trigger the recalculation. Please let me know if this worked so that I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check the calculation order of the form fields ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7de2.w.html ).

Or, calling this.calculateNow() will force calculation of all the calculation fields on the form.  Refer to Adobe's PDF API reference here: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf